# What is the reverse of the new RegExp() constructor?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegExp problem that I need help with.
I have two strings `str1 = "abcde $a1$ cdeg $x$ fghj $v8$ ABCDEa1FGH $a1$ LMN"`and `str2 = "NMNa1CD (a1+x)/(v8-x+a1) dgd"`. I replaced `T1` for `a1`, `T2` for `x`, `T3` for `v8` in `str1` (those between `$...$`). Now I want to replace according to that rule (`T1` for `a1,...`) in `str2`, but only the elements in the mathematical expression, I did the following:
I take out all the elements between `$..$` in `str1` (`a1`, `x`, `v8`) to form an array:
I extracted all the elements between `$..$` in the string `str1` to form an array:

```
var $str$ = str1.match(/\$+[^$]+\$/g).toString();
var str = $str$.substring(1,$str$.length-1);
var wr = str.match(/\w\d|[a-z]/g);
var newWr = unique(wr);//here is a function that merges duplicate elements in an array
```

I then find and replace the elements in the string str2:

```
for (var i =0;i <= newWr.length-1;i++){
  var x = newWr[i];
var str2 = str2.replace(x,"T"+(i+1));
Logger.log(str2);
```

Of course when running the above code, all `a1`, `x`, `v8` elements will be replaced. While I just want to replace the elements that are in the math expression `(a1+x)/(v8-x+a1)`. I used RegExp as follows

```
var str2 = str2.replace(/x(?=\W)/g,"T"+(i+1));
```

But it didn't work. I have researched a lot about RegExp but I have not found a solution. I ask for your help, thanks.

Comment: how would you define what is in the expression? Anything between ( and )?

Comment: I'd also point out that the string version of `replace` only replaces the FIRST occurrence.

Comment: I only need to apply the condition: After the character is not a letter or number (`\W`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct, but the `x` in the regex should be the value of variable `x` not letter `x`. So the following should fix that issue.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= newWr.length - 1; i++) {
    let x = newWr[i];
    const regex = new RegExp(`${x}(?=\\W)`, 'g');
    str2 = str2.replace(regex, "T" + (i + 1));
}
console.log(str2); // NMNa1CD (T1+T2)/(T3-T2+T1) dgd
```

Comment: I read here: [link]( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_constructor), but really I don't understand. And that's great, you helped me understand this problem, thank **Udith Gunaratna** very much!

Comment: @Letone If the above answer worked, please mark it as the accepted answer.